# Have to run rmmod b43 ; sudo rmmod bcma ; sudo rmmod wl ; sudo modprobe wl after restart?

Tags: networking, broadcom, b43

I have a Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01) and unless I run `rmmod b43 ; sudo rmmod bcma ; sudo rmmod wl ; sudo modprobe wl` after restart, the wireless device isn't available in network devices. Is there a way of making it work without having to modprobe the device issues?

Comment: Use `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to figure out if I should be running this or fixing the problem so I don't have to run it. Should all the commands go on differet lines with or without sudo in rc.local?

Comment: Without `sudo`, they can be on same or different lines (as long as the `;` are retained). You could add these lines, and then look into fixing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `/etc/rc.local` is not the efficient way to do this. I suggest, from a terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist b43"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist bcma"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo wl  >>  /etc/modules
exit
```

Reboot and you should be all set.